# Alias an Eloquent relationship when eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to alias a Eloquent relationship when eager loading?  For example, I might have a query such as the following.

```
User::with(['roles' => function ($query) { $query->where('type', ADMIN); }]);
```

But what if I also want to eager load roles with a status of ACTIVE?  The only way I can think of doing it is to duplicate the roles relationship on the User model and give it a different name.  The query would then look something like the following.

```
User::with([
  'roles' => function ($query) { $query->where('type', ADMIN); },
  'otherRoles' => function ($query) { $query->where('status', ACTIVE) }]
);
```

I could have methods such as `adminRoles` and `activeRoles` on my user model, but that's really not what I am looking for as there are so many possible parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've indicated you don't want to have additional methods on your user model, but that's the best approach you've got apart from using closures like you are already. You can improve the code a little bit by having your new methods like `adminRoles` leverage the existing relationship method, and a scope provided by the related model.

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function adminRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles()->admin();
    }
}
```

Then define the scopes you want to use on your `Role` model.

```
class Role extends Eloquent
{
    public function scopeAdmin($query)
    {
        $query->where('type', static::ADMIN);
    }
}
```

And you can now eager load these scoped relationships.

```
User::with('adminRoles')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately aliasing relationships when eager loading is not currently possible in Laravel (8.x). It doesn't look like it'll be implemented in the near future as Taylor has closed two PRs on this.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37656#issuecomment-870604176

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/31976#issuecomment-599538731

Answer (score 0):

How about `resolveRelationUsing`? You can create your custom relationship name at your function on the fly:

```
User::resolveRelationUsing('otherRoles', function (User $userModel) {
    return $userModel->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
});
```

and then eager load that `otherRoles` relationship:

```
User::with([
  'roles' => function ($query) { $query->where('type', ADMIN); },
  'otherRoles' => function ($query) { $query->where('status', ACTIVE) }]
);
```